# Appending to the dom inside each iteration or create an array and output?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, dom

I posted [a question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231447/jquery-parsing-json-data-having-trouble-with-variable-name) dealing with parsing json data. In one of the follow up answers someone said I was taking a performance hit by using the jQuery append() function within each iteration, while using each().

I was doing:

```
$.getJSON("http://myurl.com/json?callback=?", 
  function(data) {        

  // loop through each post 
  $.each(data.posts, function(i,posts){ 

    ... parsing ...

    // append
    $('ul').append('<li>...</li>');

  }); 

 });
```

I modified it to be this:

```
$.getJSON("http://myurl.com/json?callback=?", 
  function(data) { 

     // create array
     arrPosts = new Array(); 

      // loop through each post
      $.each(data.posts, function(i,posts){ 

       ... parsing ...

        arrPosts[i] = '<li> ... </li>'; 

      });           

      // output
      for (i=0;i<arrPosts.length;i++){ 
        $('ul').append(arrPosts[i]); 
      } 

  });
```

And this seems to be working properly, example demo: http://jsbin.com/isuro

But am I doing this right? I'm somewhat of a noob and just want to make sure I'm approaching this correctly. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shouldn't have to iterate to output.

```
$('ul').append( arrPosts.join( "\n" ) );
```

Otherwise looks fine

Comment: Works perfectly. I obviously need to read up on working with javascript arrays. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You are still doing it wrong. The point is you don't want to modify DOM in a loop, because it's just so slow. You were adding items to an array so then you can just add all of them in one function call:

```
$('ul').append(arrPosts.join(''));
```

Answer (score 1):

In most browsers it will be quicker to append one large HTML string than to perform multiple small appends. Thus

```
 $('ul').append( arrPosts.join( "\n" ) );
```

Should yield better results than

```
  for (i=0;i<arrPosts.length;i++){ 
    $('ul').append(arrPosts[i]); 
  }
```

(Obviously, this difference is significant only if you are adding a large number of elements)